# Confused about why it's useful to unit test dummy objects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm reading `Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship` and one of the examples involves a `Portfolio` class and a `TokyoStockExchange` class. However, `Portfolio` is not very testable because it depends on `TokyoStockExchange` as an external API to determine the value of the portfolio and such is quite a volatile lookup and not conducive to testing.

So, they solve this by creating a common `StockExchange` interface and have `TokyoStockExchange` and `DummyStockExchange` both implement the base class. Thus, dependency inversion principle is attained and in the `PortfolioTest` class one can instantiate a `DummyStockExchange`, fix a stock price to a corporation, assign the `DummyStockExchange` instance to the portfolio, and add some stocks from that company to the portfolio, and then assert if the expected value is indeed the proper value. Here's the code:

```
public class PortfolioTest
{
    private DummyStockExchange exchange;
    private Portfolio portfolio;

    protected void setUp()
    {
        exchange = new DummyStockExchange();
        exchange.fix("MSFT", 100);
        portfolio = new Portfolio(exchange);
    }

    public void GivenFiveMSFTTotalShouldBe500()
    {
        portfolio.add(5, "MSFT");
        Assert.assertEquals(500, portfolio.value());
    }
}
```

My question, simply, is *why*?

We were trying test if the `TokyoStockExchange` class worked in tandem with the `Portfolio` class. Obviously if we create another class with a new method that sets a stock price and then give the portfolio five of those stocks then everything will work. It just seems.. useless to test. I understand that `TokyoStockExchange` is basically impossible to test with `Portfolio` because of the changing stock prices but I don't understand how subbing in a rather useless test helps the situation.

It all just seems akin to not knowing if our adder programs works but the only numbers available are randomly generated so we create a dummy class that gives us a 2 and test if `2 + 2 = 4`. Well yeah, obviously that is true. We can still break `TokyoStockExchange` and the test will still succeed because it's testing another class. If anything this all seems deceptive and it also results in having to write additional code just to test something we know is going to work.

I think this is the biggest problem I have with understanding Unit Testing at this point. I know that I'm wrong I just have failed to see the light I guess. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: For reference...if you're testing that `TokyoStockExchange` works *with* `Portfolio`, you're outside the scope of unit testing.  `Portfolio` and `TokyoStockExchange` are units, and unit testing is intended to test each *unit* separately from as many others as possible (preferably all).  The interaction between them is what *integration tests* cover.

Comment: +1 for trying to understand the value rather than blowing off unit testing with "it's more work to maintain that code, too"

Comment: This is really more of a question for [programmers.se].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is that you would want to test the logic in the `Portfolio` class in isolation from `TokyoStockExchange`. If you use a mock framework like Moq or Rhino Mocks, then you can easily simulate different outputs and behaviors from `TokyoStockExchange` and write unit tests to make sure that `Portfolio` responds correctly. You would write separate unit tests for the `TokyoStockExchange` class.

This is not to say that you don't need *integration* testing between the two classes. It's just hard to properly verify all scenarios without the use of mock objects.

It's hard to understand the value with such a simple class as an example, but given a more complex class where you need to verify test cases for situations which are hard to or impossible to arrange on a "live" class, unit testing becomes much more important.

Comment: +1 Exactly.  You're not testing the TokyoStockExchange, you're testing that the Portfolio class works correctly.

Comment: To add: You want to test in isolation so when a test does fail it's easier to find the root cause.  If you run an integration test with 20 different classes in play and it "fails", you could spend a lot of time looking through 20 classes for the root cause.  If you stub out a bunch (like 19) and get a granularity down to one class, you drastically reduce the surface area you have to search/fix.

Comment: Also, by creating an absolute known **dependency**, you remove **variability** from the question of the test.  This creates a baseline from which you can say "This object works exactly as expected  when given standard or expected input."  Consider, instead, that the dependency creates a database connection but that connection fails for some reason... you don't want this test to fail because that's not representative of what you're testing.

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of tests you should be doing, unit tests and integration tests.

A unit test is supposed to be a white-box test where you test every unit of code in isolation. Generally this refers to your public interfaces in each class. You mock out their dependencies so that you are assured that given a known set of data, your unit will return predictable results.

You say, "obviously everything will work" in the unit test. That presupposes that you don't have any bugs in your code. If you could make that assumption then you would not need to test anything in the first place! And you don't really need to unit test everything---if your `Portfolio` is just a thin layer on top of your `StockExchange` that calls API methods and passes along the results, you shouldn't bother unit testing it.

On the other hand, if your `Portfolio` has real logic in it, you would want to unit test it. Let's say `Portfolio` has a method to pull data from the `Stock Exchange`, analyze the data, and send an alert message to a user when the stock price shows some anomaly, such as if the price starts to drop rapidly. You'd want to make sure that the alert is actually going to be triggered sent under the expected conditions, but you don't want to sit around and wait for the next stock market crash. So in your unit test, you'd make a mock `Stock Exchange` that produces the kinds of values that you want to trigger the alert, and then check that it actually happens. If it does, great, if not, you just found a bug.

Integration testing will test the two units in tandem, and is also important. But it's more difficult to simulate certain kinds of scenarios in integration testing, and it's less helpful in figuring out where a bug is actually hiding. If you ran an integration test for your application and found that it wasn't sending alerts when it should be, where is the problem? Is there a bug in the third-party API? Is the stock exchange sending you bad values? Is your alert system sending messages to the wrong address? It might take a while for you to figure out that there was an issue with your analysis method.